# Change width of a certain page (no impact on source code)

Tags: html, css

I have a page which I use often to check some stuff, but it's not developed by me.
On this page, there is a label which is always to small and to read it completly, I go always to dev console, search the label and change the width manually.

This annoys me, is there a possibility to set the value fixed for myself? or with a chrome plugin so that I don't have to do it all the times?

[image]

This is the page, when I've loaded it:
[image]

You can see the yellow boarder, it's not wide enought, that I can see the whole text.
So to see it, I always open Developer Console and change the width of this css class to a width of 400px.
default it's set to 250px.

I'd like to find a way, that I don't have to do that every time manually.
But I don't have impact on the code, I'm not a developer of the page. Just a user.
And couldn't finde a solution, if there is a plugin or another way, how I can configure chrome that for this page, this width of the class will be changed automatically.

Comment: If you can elaborate more about your problem, maybe we can help you.

Comment: sure, edited above

Answer (score 0):

Try to add !important in your css code as there might be the case in your browser so go with an important tag hope it will help you to resolve your query

Comment: but I don't own any sourcecode, it's just like a random page which I'd like to appear everytime I open it the same width